# Have a question about bivariate random vector

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

When X follows beta (2,2) and X = x, the conditional distribution of Y is the binomial distribution B (15, x). The probability mass function P (Y = y) of E (X), Var (X), E (Y), and Var (Y) obtained by generating random numbers of Bivariate random vectors compare with theoretical values.

R is used to obtain the software value, but I do not know how to obtain the theoretical value.

Comment: Use [total probability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and also see total expectation,total variance in the [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#See_also) pages. If this is [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), please add the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_X(x) =  \tfrac{1}{B(2,2)}x(1-x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x) = 6x(1-x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$ et $\mathbb{P}[Y=y|X=x] = {15\choose y}x^y(1-x)^{15-y}$

Donc $$\mathbb{P}[Y=y] = \int \mathbb{P}[Y=y|X=x]f_X(x)dx = \int_0^1 {15\choose y}x^y(1-x)^{15-y}6x(1-x)dx$$
$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y] = 6{15\choose y}B(y+2,17-y)\int_0^1\tfrac{1}{B(y+2,17-y)}x^{y+1}(1-x)^{16-y}dx $$
$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y] = 6{15\choose y}B(y+2,17-y) = \tfrac{1}{816}\left[-y^2+15y+16\right] (*) $$

For the expectations, we have, $\mathbb{E}[X] = \tfrac{2}{2+2}=\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{V}ar[X] = \tfrac{2*2}{(2+2)^2(2+2+1)} = \tfrac{1}{20}$

For $Y$, you can compute it by use the formula of expectation and variance and the mass density in $(*)$

Comment: Thanks very much!! So how is the range determined?

Comment: The beta distribustion is between 0 and 1 (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and the binomial distribution is between 0 to n (here n=15).